# Is there an API for Instagrams "Archive Media" feature?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I'm looking to write a little bit of software that can archive large amounts of photos programmatically, but I can't seem to find an API endpoint for that and I wasn't sure if I was missing something.

Answer (score 0):

I've been searching and I believe the answer is no. It seems many of the unofficial APIs also dont have it,  I suppose due to its relative newness.